# Installing Ubuntu as D: drive partition on HDD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, drivers, partitioning, hard-drive

I want to use Ubuntu on my external hard drive by shrinking into a partition. I use both SSD and external hard drive on my PC and both are installed Windows 10. My external hard drive has 931 GB available capacity and I shrink its volume as 150 GB unallocated and 781 GB NTFS formatted partitions. 
Does that mean this unallocated part also have NTFS format or not?

Also, When I configure boot options from BIOS. I see a Partition 1 when I use my Ubuntu installed USB stick. 
If I choose Partition 1, would it also install Ubuntu on my 781 GB NTFS formatted partition?
To make it clear I am sharing my disk management page for my PC.

[image: my disk management page]

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You show an efi system partition (ESP) on first drive. Is second drive also gpt partitioned? Windows requires gpt for UEFI boot. Ubuntu can install on MBR or gpt in either the 35 year old BISO/MBR configuration or newer UEFI/gpt. You really want Ubuntu in UEFI on gpt partitioned drive.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI & This is to same drive, but otherwise similar to what you want since you still have an NTFS on external drive. http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi If you want exteral to boot on other systems, you must add an ESP

Answer (score 0):

When you start installing Ubuntu it will ask you a option like this- [Installation Type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FL7NT.jpg)

You will be asked here if you want to erase the disk or do something else.Select something else.Here select the unallocated partition of 150 GB(in your case). [Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h7XkD.jpg)

This way data from the disk will not be deleted(in your case 781 GB).

In response to your other question-No,unallocated part does not have NTFS format until you format it as NTFS or some other file system.